# Incorrect order of subscribed sites in app left-swipe list

Tags: bug, android-app

***This bug affects both the tablet and phone app.***

The last item in the reorder list section becomes the second item in the left-swipe list.

Here are images showing the issue.
Reorder screen shows desirable order of subs which is correct (Notice user-experience is at the bottom):

Nexus 7 (2013) & S4 Mini:

> [image]

Now this is the sidebar with the bug (notice user-experience is now second in the left-swipe list even though it has been set to be at the bottom):

Nexus 7 (2013) & S4 Mini:

> [image]

**Bug reproduction:** Moving any sub to the bottom in the reorder screen results in that sub being second in the left-swipe list.

Bug occurs on both Nexus 7 (2013) tablet & Samsung S4 Mini phone.